# Why my Mathematica 9.0.1 wont work with some samples of Mathematica in Graph Theory?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, mathematical-optimization, version-9

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.0**

 `FindMinimumCostFlow` is introduced in 9.0.

---

I updated my *Mathematica* recently to 9.0.1 cause the previous version was giving me freaky result especially in `FindMinimumCostFlow` and `OptimumFlowData`. But even in new version I have problems.It can not still solve the multi-source multi-sink problem even the same example of *Mathematica* [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindMinimumCostFlow.html) such as first of basic examples:

```
FindMinimumCostFlow[
 Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
   UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[1, 5], 
   UndirectedEdge[5, 6], UndirectedEdge[6, 4], UndirectedEdge[2, 5], 
   UndirectedEdge[3, 6]}, {ImageSize -> 110, 
   VertexShapeFunction -> {"Name"}}], 
{1, 3, 4, -3, -4, -1}]
```

After evaluation it doesn't return any result. Can somebody help me on that?

Comment: A couple of things. First, you are trying to post the full box structure of something, and stackexchange does not interpret that correctly. Since you mention the documentation, can you post a link to it and someone might be able to get something better working. Second, the grave marks ( ` ) are for _inline_ formatting only. To set up a code block, indent by four spaces.

Comment: OK.did it.and my OS is Mac 10.6.8

Comment: I put the `InputForm` of the graph into a code block. Look at the [revisions][http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/25410/revisions] to see what I did, or better yet, the [edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/25410/edit) window.

Comment: @rcollyer That input crashes the kernel. You will report it?

Comment: @rcollyer The graph related functionality in particular seems to have too many bugs. :-(

Comment: @Szabolcs already reported.

Comment: @Szabolcs and @rcollyer when do you expecting the bugs to be removed.Actually I can see more in the bigger graphs I created.Surprisingly even disconnected highlighted optimized flows in `FlowGraph`. I spend a lot of time for this project and cant change the compiler.What are your recommendations?

Comment: @Alex At this site we are just users like you.  But when you find bugs like this, you can and should report them to support@wolfram.com and ask them about when it might get fixed.